# Responsive div blocks with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Okay so, for a school assignment I have to make these blocks responsive and changing rows when on a certain screen width, above 1024px they have to be 2 rows going horizontally, and below 1024px 2 rows going vertically, always spelling out 'LOI'. I kind of got the result using flexbox and making the flex-direction change using a media query. But now I want the blocks being responsive so that there is no gap in between the blocks when resizing the screen (so the blocks are always the same size). Does anyone know the solution? Thanks in advance!

```css
main {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: auto;
}

.blokken {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 1200px;
  align-content: stretch;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .blokken {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.letter {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 5px solid black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Nederland versteend</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>


    <h2 id="letterblokjes">Letterblokjes</h2>

    <div class="blokken">
      <div class="letter">L</div>
      <div class="letter">O</div>
      <div class="letter">I</div>
      <div class="letter">L</div>
      <div class="letter">O</div>
      <div class="letter">I</div>
    </div>


  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can use `align-content: center` for that they always be in the center. Since it has `flex-direction: column` for the screen below 1024px.(And in this case, `align-content` and `align-items` will be for horizontal alignment)

```css
main {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: auto;
}

.blokken {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 1200px;
  align-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .blokken {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.letter {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 5px solid black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h2 id="letterblokjes">Letterblokjes</h2>
  <div class="blokken">
    <div class="letter">L</div>
    <div class="letter">O</div>
    <div class="letter">I</div>
    <div class="letter">L</div>
    <div class="letter">O</div>
    <div class="letter">I</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! That really helped! Now one more thing. When the screen size is at let's say 650px, i want that the blocks to get smaller, so it still fits in a mobile screen. Do you have a simple answer for that aswell?

Comment: @JelleAkkerman You're welcome. In this case, do you want to retain the ratio of them(ratio of same width and height)?

Comment: I also edited my answer for a case.